# Adding raster layers to Layer panel in QGIS with hidden visibility

Tags: raster, pyqgis, layers

I am adding raster images to a QGIS project by clicking into the map window (using an Action on a vector layer):

```
from qgis.utils import iface
layerpath = os.path.dirname( iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
rasterurl = "...."
iface.addRasterLayer(rasterurl, "[%Datum%]")
```

As the number of images can be high, is it possible to add these to the Layer panel with hidden visibility?

The `addRasterLayer` method doesn't seem to have an option for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `iface.addRasterLayer()` method returns a `QgsRasterLayer` object. So, if you assign the return value of the method call to a variable, you can get the corresponding `QgsLayerTreeNode` object and 'uncheck' it via something like:

```
lyr = iface.addRasterLayer(rasterurl, "[%Datum%]")
tree_lyr = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(lyr.id())
tree_lyr.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm.

Comment: @DNase, that's great. No problem :-)